# what program should i use with a gzip archive

Tags: gzip

I am trying to download grub-1.99.tar.gz ,I do not know what program to use to open  a

Gzip file. please recommend

Comment: You can use [tar](http://www.manpager.com/linux/man1/tar.1.html).

Comment: Why no use `file-roller` or "archive manager" which is  default in ubuntu installations.

Comment: @Jobin definitely not a dupe, that's specific to a .zip file, not a tarball or gz file

Answer (score 2):

What you actually have is a tarball, so you'll want to use the `tar` command.

```
 tar -zxvf grub-1.99.tar.gz
```

If you had a file that was only `.gz` (and not `.tar.gz`) you would use

```
gunzip grub-199.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

Musher is spot-on.  Here is what those `tar` flags mean (taken from `man tar`):

```
-f, --file ARCHIVE
       use archive file or device ARCHIVE
-v, --verbose
       verbosely list files processed
-x, --extract, --get
       extract files from an archive
-z, --gzip, --gunzip --ungzip
```

So executing `tar -zxvf grub-1.99.tar.gz` should extract everything from that `.tar.gz.` file, and list-out each file as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Nearly every compressed file may be extracted using this method.

Answer (score 0):

`p7zip` can handle most formats including gzip